# Nginx proxy request to url specified in GET variable

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I need Nginx to respond to a request like

```
https://example.org/proxy/?url=https://othersite.com/path/file.php%%a=test123%%b=321tset
```

or a similar method, like

```
https://example.org/proxy/https://othersite.com/path/file.php?a=test123&b=321tset
```

by proxying the request to

```
https://othersite.com/path/file.php?a=test123&b=321tset
```

Is there a way to do this with rewriting or a different rule? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You are sending open invitation to all malicious actors to use your server as a gateway to attack other websites. Don't do this without proper restrictions on proxy targets.

Comment: You don't know my situation. This is going to be on a local server.

Comment: In that case it is fine. Just wanted to warn in general about the dangers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SE. Those redirects can be done using `if` statements and I've not tried it using nginx proxy.

Add the following `if` blocks to your Nginx `server` block to redirect them as required

```
server {
    ...
    ...

    #For https://example.org/proxy/?url=https://othersite.com/path/file.php%%a=test123%%b=321tset

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/proxy/\?url=(.*)$) {
        return 301 $1;
    }

    #For https://example.org/proxy/https://othersite.com/path/file.php?a=test123&b=321tset

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/proxy/(https\:\/\/(.*))$) {
        return 301 $1;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can use proxy using `location` blocks instead of using `if`

```
location ~ /proxy/\?url=(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass $1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location ~ /proxy/https\:\/\/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass $1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```